# Can't figure why this INSERT INTO sql doesn't work in HTML Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I'm having difficulties finding the trouble maker in my codes, when i try to create a "Create a Project" form, after i made a secure login system.

What i'm interested in, is to make a form that can INSERT a project into my database, after you logged in. Like my website is all about crowdfunding, and i want users to be able to create project name and a goal for their projects, at first.

I've been using a wikihow guide to make the secure login system, and it works.
Here is my code and sources:

```html
<?php
include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (pname, pgoal) VALUES ('$pname','$pgoal')";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Secure Login: Registration Form</title>
   <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script>
   <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Registration form to be output if the POST variables are not
set or if the registration script caused an error. -->
<h1>Project Register</h1>
<?php
if (!empty($error_msg)) {
    echo $error_msg;
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Project Name: <input type='text' name='pname' id='pname' /><br>
    Project Goal: <input type="number" name="pgoal" id="pgoal" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>

<p>Return to the <a href="index.php">login page</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

SOURCE:
[WikiHow - How to create a Secure..](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Comment: Stop. Do not proceed until you learn about SQL injection. Unless you feel like dealing with a visit from [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Do you set `$pname` and `$pgoal`? Also see above, SQL injections will wreck your day.

Comment: the query is never actually run, all you do is create a string with the query in it

Comment: No man, this is a mess, nothing's going anywhere here, it's like we would have to start from scratch

Comment: I made it clear in the question that i used a guide, which includes the connection in another php folder, and the direction is in the posted link called "Source" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the follow:

This:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (pname, pgoal) VALUES ('$pname','$pgoal')";
```

Doesn't do anything

But this:

```
$pname = $_POST['pname'];
$pgoal = $_POST['pgoal'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO projects (pname, pgoal) VALUES ('$pname','$pgoal')";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query);

if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Could do something.

**NOTE**

I'm not taking `injection`  in consideration, I'm just want you to see that you need a connection.

**PLUS**

Some of the comments are right, you need to set variables and you are just creating a variable called `$query`

**EDIT**

your code could look more organize if you separate html from php

**INSERT.PHP**

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

   $sql = "INSERT INTO projects (pname, pgoal) VALUES ('$pname','$pgoal')";

   $plus what I added early

   ?>
```

**HTML**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Secure Login: Registration Form</title>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Registration form to be output if the POST variables are not
  set or if the registration script caused an error. -->
  <h1>Project Register</h1>

  <form action="insert.php" method="post">
  Project Name: <input type='text' name='pname' id='pname' /><br>
  Project Goal: <input type="number" name="pgoal" id="pgoal" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
  </form>

  <p>Return to the <a href="index.php">login page</a>.</p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This alone won't help the OP, he has a lot to learn (which isn't a bad thing, but we need to help by providing more information). First off, `$pname` and `$pgoal` don't exist. They need to be retrieved via `$_POST`. Secondly, you don't want the SQL to run on every page load; you only want it to run if there's `$_POST` data. I think it would be really helpful if you updated your answer to include these things, so that we have one single answer that covers all points.

Comment: I know, this is why I wrote the **note** I can't just post write a comment saying "go and learn", I would like the user to see at least why his/her code is not working.

Comment: So where should i put these POST data's that i'm unsure with.

Comment: I have a connection that is termed within alot of defines:
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';   // As functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE); ?>

Comment: A Madruo, the $_POST that i added before the $sql helped getting the page running without errors. But it's still not inserting any data into my db

Comment: yes, again those are variables, you need to use them by passing it.  But, you still need to learn more about php and html working together with sql.    [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) W3School could help you to understand it more.

Comment: Please do some research on **INSERT INTO in php**, there is no point to tell you only one thing, we could take a lot space here in  a Q/A lol.  You will find better solutions only, including the one that Christian Vargas said, that you don't want the sql to run on every page load

Comment: Yea i know it's not that easy to help out with one simple page when i got a 20 php pages for this project atm. Actually i just wanted to know if someone had experiences with the WikiHow secure login system, since it seems that it's blockin my submit and INSERT INTO function.

Comment: I hope my answer and comments can help you.  Good luck

Comment: @JonasL Please, don't forget to accept the best answer, thank you.

Comment: Of course. Seems like you get low rep, if you're asking beginners questions in Stackoverflow. :(